# Getting 404 error when visiting /embed/ on a particular post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

On a Wordpress installation we have, we've added multiple custom post types but we're having a strange issue with a particular post type. When trying to embed a post from this custom post type into another article, we're shown a 404 page. It seems that if we try to visit the post's embed url directly (eg: website.com/blog/blog-post/embed/) we also get a 404 error.

To specify, this is a multisite installation and as mentioned, this issue is only happening on 1 particular custom post type - all others work when embedded without any issues.

We've refreshed permalinks and checked our custom post type registration code but this is exactly like all others from what we could see. What would be a good place to start debugging this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check post / custom post / pages tags. also check category name permalinks is same or not

Comment: Turns out tags was the problem - it was matching the same permalink as main custom post type. Thanks @hasan for your help. Managed to find the issue easily with this [https://gist.github.com/soulseekah/2321074] - kudos to author

Comment: sorry, which gist?
I have the same issue with a custom post type's /embed returning 404 but ?embed=true not